# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variable

Tags: php

Please I'm getting this error.
Please help me
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
This is the code
static public function mdlSalesDatesRange($table, $initialDate, $finalDate){

```
    if($initialDate == null){

        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id ASC");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll(); 


    }else if($initialDate == $finalDate){

        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE saledate like'%$finalDate%'");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":saledate", $finalDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt-> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
```

Comment: Instead of `WHERE saledate like '%$finalDate%'` did you mean `WHERE saledate like concat('%', :saledate, '%')`

Answer (score 0):

You're appending data within the string and then binding parameters for non-existent placeholders. You need to follow the syntax specified in the docs. [mysql bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```html
$stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE saledate like'%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $table_name, $final_date);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: it's still not working